# Monitor network activity using WMI in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, wmi

Is there a WMI query to monitor network connections; not network adapter connect/disconnect nor wifi network connect/disconnect, but rather something like the output of `netstat` ~ 5-tuple: `(source IP address, source IP port, destination IP address, destination IP port, process ID)`, by specifying some event callback, instead of repeatedly (polling at regular intervals then doing a `diff`), or sniffing network packets? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any API that will give you callbacks for this and any solution would be based on polling anyway.

**However**

You could write a [Dll injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) utility as a *Windows Service*, that hooks a few targeted *WinSock2* functions like `Connect` ect, and stores the information you need which could then be accessible via some sort of *IPC*.

[Windows Sockets 2 (Windows) - MSDN - Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Interprocess Communications (Windows) - MSDN - Microsoft](https://www.google.com.au/search?ei=Uq2DWtvGJcWd0gSup6yYBA&q=interprocess%20communication%20windows&oq=interprocess%20communication%20windows&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1l2j0i22i30k1l3j0i13i5i30k1l5.1889.2611.0.2728.3.3.0.0.0.0.206.206.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.205....0.aTy5TEwovJE)

A couple of concerns would be

- Keeping track of newly loaded processes. *however with the help of a Kernel Mode driver you can hook the load and unload of processes*
- Processes that aren't using *WinSock2* (im not sure how far down this rabbit hole you want to go). *Maybe you could monitor something more fundamental at the driver level (though i'm not sure)*

Once your hooking architecture is done, you can then expose some sort of *IPC* so your user mode monitor can extract the information it needs...

*I was faced with a similar problem at previous job when we had to hook printing functions for 32 and 64 applications to monitor print jobs and metrics. In short, this is completely possible and actually not that hard to do if you don't mind a bit of C++*

Most of this work can be done for you with the help of Libs like [madCodeHook](http://www.madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm) developed by Mathias Rauen. He has already developed the drivers, and a great API for for tracking processes and the various tricks to DLL Injection.

Anyway, Good Luck